# Function keys since upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: keyboard, macos

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> takes me to Display preferences, instead of using the current app binding, as it did in Mavericks. Is there any way to override this behavior?

I can't find the binding in Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

I see the binding on the Apple [shortcut page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343), and I think it's always been there, but previously applications could overrule the setting.

If it's relevant, the app in question is [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem came from the external keyboard, a [Logitech K750](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/8424). I had to use the [Logitech Control Center](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/8424#download) to get the correct behavior. Why this wasn't a problem in Mavericks, I'm not sure.