# Yosemite Upgrade changed numeric keypad "Enter" key to issue "^[33OM"

Tags: macos, keybindings

On Mavericks and previous, the "ENTER" key on the numeric keypad mimicked  the "ENTER" key on the main keyboard.  I can't find a way to map this back to working like an "ENTER" key again.  Where this is showing up is while using the Terminal app in xterm emulation.  It is only a problem in Terminal.  I am using a full size Logitech Illuminated K740 keyboard.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated. This has been my default/habitual Enter key.

Thanks in advance for clues...

Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I found the simplest answer...  In Terminal Preferrences, Advanced Tab, I **unchecked** the box in the 'Input' options section: "Allow VT100 application keypad mode"

Now the keypad ENTER key is identical to the main keyboard ENTER key!

Simple and sweet, I found this when looking through the TMUX help information.

I didn't realize that the only place where the keypad ENTER was issuing "\EOM" was in my tmux sessions, since that is the default mode in my remote admin sessions.  Thanks for the information above, but this was all I needed to do.  I've I'd given more background people may have had better clues.

Answer (score 1):

Try remapping it using the Logitech Control Center for OS X or any official Logitech software that's supposed to work with your keyboard model. Based on [the answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151844/function-keys-since-upgrading-to-yosemite), which states that the user had to use Logitech Control Center to get a key remapped correctly, it seems Yosemite handles non-Apple keyboards a little differently compared to Mavericks.